# PHP: can anyone explain this Exception Handler error?

Tags: php

hi can anyone here can help how to determine whats the error on here? please i really need to know. thank you in advance guys! help me to figure out what is wrong with the codes below.

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstir, $errfile, $errline ) {
throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);;
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
strpos();
```

i don't know whats the error on this but it stills keeping an error output. pls help me guys

Comment: What is the error output?  I am seeing Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' when I test your code.  Do you intend to catch this exception somewhere?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the "error output".  Help us help you.  The Stackoverflow guidelines are useful.

Comment: no i just need to explain or know why it has error? what is the reason why there is error in this code? my teacher asked me about this if how can I explain why this code has an error :(

Comment: Well the code intentionally calls `strpos()` with no parameters, which will definitely trigger an exception.  Your code registers the function `exception_error_handler` to handle the exception

Comment: i see thank you so much tim thats what i wonder too. i just need to be sure! thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP notices and warnings don't throw exceptions. Calling strpos() without parameters is a warning. That function registers your custom function as the error_handler, which basically converts all notices and warnings to an exception. It' useful for development and debugging, and a lot of frameworks use something like that to show error pages in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following code which catches the custom ErrorException which you `throw`?:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstir, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);;
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    /* Trigger exception */
    strpos();
    echo 'No exception was thrown';
}

//catch exception
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort to answer mate but i just need explanation why there  is an error. what happen on this line of code why there error? :)